# EMGU CV videowriter is unable to make video

Tags: c#, opencv, bitmap, emgucv, image-compression

I was trying to capture video using Emgu CV VideoWriter but it shows:

> Unable to create VideoWriter. Make sure you have the specific codec
>   installed

How do I deal with this?
This is what my code looks like:

```
Bitmap back = new Bitmap("jpg image path");
Image<Bgr, Byte> bg;
bg = new Image(Bgr, byte)(back);
vw = new VideoWriter("c://work//test1.mp4",CvInvoke.CV_FOURCC('M','S','V','C'), 17, 640, 480, true);
```

It works fine for .avi extensions but the size is pretty huge for some seconds only so I want to compress it more. Please suggest any workarounds or  changes to the code/library.

Answer (score 11):

I also have seen this issue. Its a real pain because Emgu CV is such a good platform for beginners!

As there are about ten Forum Questions relating to this topic and all remain unanswered and un solved across different boards on the net, I thought this warrants more attention.

See: http://www.fourcc.org/codecs.php for the FOURCC Codec Codes.

The C++ Code:

```
cout << "Codec Value: " << CV_FOURCC('D', 'I', 'V', '3') << endl;
```

Returns: 861292868

The C# Code:

```
return Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.CV_FOURCC('D', 'I', 'V', '3');
```

Returns: 861292868

So the problem is not in the Function/Method "CV_FOURCC" it must be in the passing of this Variable in the assigned Codec:

```
int Codec = Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.CV_FOURCC('D', 'I', 'V', '3');
Emgu.CV.VideoWriter(path, Codec, 20, 640, 480, true);
```

The Emgu.CV.VideoWriter class is the only thing I can see that can be the problem. The Documentation does not state any known issues of this kind:

http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/1.3.0.0/html/3fb90645-ecc4-0c4e-b238-6d0ca38f4ebc.htm

and:

http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/1.3.0.0/html/a3e01212-2f4e-6ac8-7c74-77ddb5c16299.htm

Is this an Answer, no, its a proposition for further investigation into the Emgu.CV.VideoWriter class.

**EDIT**

According to the documentation, a -1 should bring up the "codec selection dialog" window.

Using C++ and OpenCV this window does appear and you can choose from the Installed Codecs installed on your Computer:

[image: C++ OpenCV codec selection dialog]

Using C# and Emgu CV with the -1 for the Codec Dialog Selection, I get the window, but some items do not work once selecting the Codec:

[image: C# Emgu CV codec selection dialog]

As you can see the Codec Selection is not the same even though the Same PC was used.

The fact remains, using C++ and OpenCV, this line of Code works:

```
myVideoWriter = VideoWriter(path, CV_FOURCC('D', 'I', 'V', '3'), 30, fSize, true);
```

using C# and Emgu CV this line of Code does not:

```
myVideoWriter = new VideoWriter(path, CvInvoke.CV_FOURCC('D', 'I', 'V', '3'), 20, 640, 480, true);
```

**EDIT**

I ended up just using:

```
CvInvoke.CV_FOURCC('I', 'Y', 'U', 'V')
```

Which gives me pretty good compression and Video Quality. Here is a FOURCC Class I wrote to help withal this:

```
public class FourCC
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Opens the Codec Selection Dialog...
    /// </summary>
    public static int UserSelect = -1;

    public static int _1978 = 943143217;
    public static int _2VUY = 1498764850;
    public static int _3IV0 = 810961203;
    public static int _3IV1 = 827738419;
    public static int _3IV2 = 844515635;
    public static int _3IVD = 1146505523;
    public static int _3IVX = 1482049843;
    public static int _8BPS = 1397768760;
    public static int AAS4 = 877871425;
    public static int AASC = 1129529665;
    public static int ABYR = 1381581377;
    public static int ACTL = 1280590657;
    public static int ADV1 = 827737153;
    public static int ADVJ = 1247167553;
    public static int AEIK = 1263093057;
    public static int AEMI = 1229800769;
    public static int AFLC = 1129072193;
    public static int AFLI = 1229735489;
    public static int AHDV = 1447315521;
    public static int AJPG = 1196444225;
    public static int AMPG = 1196444993;
    public static int ANIM = 1296649793;
    public static int AP41 = 825512001;
    public static int AP42 = 842289217;
    public static int ASLC = 1129075521;
    public static int ASV1 = 827740993;
    public static int ASV2 = 844518209;
    public static int ASVX = 1482052417;
    public static int ATM4 = 877483073;
    public static int AUR2 = 844256577;
    public static int AURA = 1095914817;
    public static int AVC1 = 826496577;
    public static int AVRN = 1314018881;
    public static int BA81 = 825770306;
    public static int BINK = 1263421762;
    public static int BLZ0 = 811224130;
    public static int BT20 = 808604738;
    public static int BTCV = 1447253058;
    public static int BW10 = 808539970;
    public static int BYR1 = 827480386;
    public static int BYR2 = 844257602;
    public static int CC12 = 842089283;
    public static int CDVC = 1129727043;
    public static int CFCC = 1128482371;
    public static int CGDI = 1229211459;
    public static int CHAM = 1296123971;
    public static int CJPG = 1196444227;
    public static int CMYK = 1264143683;
    public static int CPLA = 1095520323;
    public static int CRAM = 1296126531;
    public static int CSCD = 1145262915;
    public static int CTRX = 1481790531;
    public static int CVID = 1145656899;
    public static int CWLT = 1414289219;
    public static int CXY1 = 827938883;
    public static int CXY2 = 844716099;
    public static int CYUV = 1448433987;
    public static int CYUY = 1498765635;
    public static int D261 = 825635396;
    public static int D263 = 859189828;
    public static int DAVC = 1129726276;
    public static int DCL1 = 827081540;
    public static int DCL2 = 843858756;
    public static int DCL3 = 860635972;
    public static int DCL4 = 877413188;
    public static int DCL5 = 894190404;
    public static int DIV3 = 861292868;
    public static int DIV4 = 878070084;
    public static int DIV5 = 894847300;
    public static int DIVX = 1482049860;
    public static int DM4V = 1446268228;
    public static int DMB1 = 826428740;
    public static int DMB2 = 843205956;
    public static int DMK2 = 843795780;
    public static int DSVD = 1146508100;
    public static int DUCK = 1262703940;
    public static int DV25 = 892491332;
    public static int DV50 = 808801860;
    public static int DVAN = 1312904772;
    public static int DVCS = 1396921924;
    public static int DVE2 = 843404868;
    public static int DVH1 = 826824260;
    public static int DVHD = 1145591364;
    public static int DVSD = 1146312260;
    public static int DVSL = 1280529988;
    public static int DVX1 = 827872836;
    public static int DVX2 = 844650052;
    public static int DVX3 = 861427268;
    public static int DX50 = 808802372;
    public static int DXGM = 1296521284;
    public static int DXTC = 1129601092;
    public static int DXTN = 1314150468;
    public static int EKQ0 = 810634053;
    public static int ELK0 = 810241093;
    public static int EM2V = 1446137157;
    public static int ES07 = 925913925;
    public static int ESCP = 1346589509;
    public static int ETV1 = 827741253;
    public static int ETV2 = 844518469;
    public static int ETVC = 1129731141;
    public static int FFV1 = 827737670;
    public static int FLJP = 1347046470;
    public static int FMP4 = 877677894;
    public static int FMVC = 1129729350;
    public static int FPS1 = 827543622;
    public static int FRWA = 1096241734;
    public static int FRWD = 1146573382;
    public static int FVF1 = 826693190;
    public static int GEOX = 1481590087;
    public static int GJPG = 1196444231;
    public static int GLZW = 1465535559;
    public static int GPEG = 1195724871;
    public static int GWLT = 1414289223;
    public static int H260 = 808858184;
    public static int H261 = 825635400;
    public static int H262 = 842412616;
    public static int H263 = 859189832;
    public static int H264 = 875967048;
    public static int H265 = 892744264;
    public static int H266 = 909521480;
    public static int H267 = 926298696;
    public static int H268 = 943075912;
    public static int H269 = 959853128;
    public static int HDYC = 1129923656;
    public static int HEVC = 1129727304;
    public static int HFYU = 1431914056;
    public static int HMCR = 1380142408;
    public static int HMRR = 1381125448;
    public static int I263 = 859189833;
    public static int ICLB = 1112294217;
    public static int IGOR = 1380927305;
    public static int IJPG = 1196444233;
    public static int ILVC = 1129729097;
    public static int ILVR = 1381387337;
    public static int IPDV = 1447317577;
    public static int IR21 = 825381449;
    public static int IRAW = 1463898697;
    public static int ISME = 1162695497;
    public static int IV30 = 808670793;
    public static int IV31 = 825448009;
    public static int IV32 = 842225225;
    public static int IV33 = 859002441;
    public static int IV34 = 875779657;
    public static int IV35 = 892556873;
    public static int IV36 = 909334089;
    public static int IV37 = 926111305;
    public static int IV38 = 942888521;
    public static int IV39 = 959665737;
    public static int IV40 = 808736329;
    public static int IV41 = 825513545;
    public static int IV42 = 842290761;
    public static int IV43 = 859067977;
    public static int IV44 = 875845193;
    public static int IV45 = 892622409;
    public static int IV46 = 909399625;
    public static int IV47 = 926176841;
    public static int IV48 = 942954057;
    public static int IV49 = 959731273;
    public static int IV50 = 808801865;

    /// <summary>
    /// This is considered to be the Dfault Fallback Codec for Linux and also Windows may be following suit.
    /// Not in the Litrature on the FOURCC website.
    /// See: http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Video_Files
    /// </summary>
    public static int IYUV = 1448433993;

    public static int JBYR = 1381581386;
    public static int JPEG = 1195724874;
    public static int JPGL = 1279742026;
    public static int KMVC = 1129729355;
    public static int L261 = 825635404;
    public static int L263 = 859189836;
    public static int LBYR = 1381581388;
    public static int LCMW = 1464681292;
    public static int LCW2 = 844579660;
    public static int LEAD = 1145128268;
    public static int LGRY = 1498564428;
    public static int LJ11 = 825313868;
    public static int LJ22 = 842156620;
    public static int LJ2K = 1261587020;
    public static int LJ44 = 875842124;
    public static int LJPG = 1196444236;
    public static int LMP2 = 844123468;
    public static int LMP4 = 877677900;
    public static int LSVC = 1129730892;
    public static int LSVM = 1297503052;
    public static int LSVX = 1482052428;
    public static int LZO1 = 827284044;
    public static int M261 = 825635405;
    public static int M263 = 859189837;
    public static int M4CC = 1128477773;
    public static int M4S2 = 844313677;
    public static int MC12 = 842089293;
    public static int MCAM = 1296122701;
    public static int MJ2C = 1127369293;
    public static int MJPG = 1196444237;
    public static int MMES = 1397050701;
    public static int MP2A = 1093816397;
    public static int MP2T = 1412583501;
    public static int MP2V = 1446137933;
    public static int MP42 = 842289229;
    public static int MP43 = 859066445;
    public static int MP4A = 1093947469;
    public static int MP4S = 1395937357;
    public static int MP4T = 1412714573;
    public static int MP4V = 1446269005;
    public static int MPEG = 1195724877;
    public static int MPG4 = 877088845;
    public static int MPGI = 1229410381;
    public static int MR16 = 909201997;
    public static int MRCA = 1094931021;
    public static int MRLE = 1162629709;
    public static int MSVC = 1129730893;
    public static int MSZH = 1213879117;
    public static int MTX1 = 827872333;
    public static int MTX2 = 844649549;
    public static int MTX3 = 861426765;
    public static int MTX4 = 878203981;
    public static int MTX5 = 894981197;
    public static int MTX6 = 911758413;
    public static int MTX7 = 928535629;
    public static int MTX8 = 945312845;
    public static int MTX9 = 962090061;
    public static int MVI1 = 826889805;
    public static int MVI2 = 843667021;
    public static int MWV1 = 827742029;
    public static int NAVI = 1230389582;
    public static int NDSC = 1129530446;
    public static int NDSM = 1297302606;
    public static int NDSP = 1347634254;
    public static int NDSS = 1397965902;
    public static int NDXC = 1129858126;
    public static int NDXH = 1213744206;
    public static int NDXP = 1347961934;
    public static int NDXS = 1398293582;
    public static int NHVU = 1431717966;
    public static int NTN1 = 827216974;
    public static int NTN2 = 843994190;
    public static int NVDS = 1396987470;
    public static int NVHS = 1397249614;
    public static int NVS0 = 810767950;
    public static int NVS1 = 827545166;
    public static int NVS2 = 844322382;
    public static int NVS3 = 861099598;
    public static int NVS4 = 877876814;
    public static int NVS5 = 894654030;
    public static int NVT0 = 810833486;
    public static int NVT1 = 827610702;
    public static int NVT2 = 844387918;
    public static int NVT3 = 861165134;
    public static int NVT4 = 877942350;
    public static int NVT5 = 894719566;
    public static int PDVC = 1129727056;
    public static int PGVV = 1448494928;
    public static int PHMO = 1330464848;
    public static int PIM1 = 827148624;
    public static int PIM2 = 843925840;
    public static int PIMJ = 1246579024;
    public static int PIXL = 1280854352;
    public static int PJPG = 1196444240;
    public static int PVEZ = 1514493520;
    public static int PVMM = 1296914000;
    public static int PVW2 = 844584528;
    public static int QPEG = 1195724881;
    public static int QPEQ = 1363497041;
    public static int RGBT = 1413629778;
    public static int RLE = 1162629727;
    public static int RLE4 = 876956754;
    public static int RLE8 = 944065618;
    public static int RMP4 = 877677906;
    public static int RPZA = 1096437842;
    public static int RT21 = 825381970;
    public static int RV20 = 808605266;
    public static int RV30 = 808670802;
    public static int RV40 = 808736338;
    public static int S422 = 842150995;
    public static int SAN3 = 860766547;
    public static int SDCC = 1128481875;
    public static int SEDG = 1195656531;
    public static int SFMC = 1129137747;
    public static int SMP4 = 877677907;
    public static int SMSC = 1129532755;
    public static int SMSD = 1146309971;
    public static int SMSV = 1448299859;
    public static int SP40 = 808734803;
    public static int SP44 = 875843667;
    public static int SP54 = 875909203;
    public static int SPIG = 1195987027;
    public static int SQZ2 = 844779859;
    public static int STVA = 1096176723;
    public static int STVB = 1112953939;
    public static int STVC = 1129731155;
    public static int STVX = 1482052691;
    public static int STVY = 1498829907;
    public static int SV10 = 808539731;
    public static int SVQ1 = 827414099;
    public static int SVQ3 = 860968531;
    public static int TLMS = 1397574740;
    public static int TLST = 1414745172;
    public static int TM20 = 808602964;
    public static int TM2X = 1479691604;
    public static int TMIC = 1128877396;
    public static int TMOT = 1414483284;
    public static int TR20 = 808604244;
    public static int TSCC = 1128485716;
    public static int TV10 = 808539732;
    public static int TVJP = 1347049044;
    public static int TVMJ = 1246582356;
    public static int TY0N = 1311791444;
    public static int TY2C = 1127373140;
    public static int TY2N = 1311922516;
    public static int UCOD = 1146045269;
    public static int ULTI = 1230261333;
    public static int V210 = 808530518;
    public static int V261 = 825635414;
    public static int V655 = 892679766;
    public static int VCR1 = 827474774;
    public static int VCR2 = 844251990;
    public static int VCR3 = 861029206;
    public static int VCR4 = 877806422;
    public static int VCR5 = 894583638;
    public static int VCR6 = 911360854;
    public static int VCR7 = 928138070;
    public static int VCR8 = 944915286;
    public static int VCR9 = 961692502;
    public static int VDCT = 1413694550;
    public static int VDOM = 1297040470;
    public static int VDOW = 1464812630;
    public static int VDTZ = 1515471958;
    public static int VGPX = 1481656150;
    public static int VIDS = 1396984150;
    public static int VIFP = 1346783574;
    public static int VIVO = 1331054934;
    public static int VIXL = 1280854358;
    public static int VLV1 = 827739222;
    public static int VP30 = 808669270;
    public static int VP31 = 825446486;
    public static int VP40 = 808734806;
    public static int VP50 = 808800342;
    public static int VP60 = 808865878;
    public static int VP61 = 825643094;
    public static int VP62 = 842420310;
    public static int VP70 = 808931414;
    public static int VP80 = 808996950;
    public static int VQC1 = 826495318;
    public static int VQC2 = 843272534;
    public static int VQJC = 1128943958;
    public static int VSSV = 1448301398;
    public static int VUUU = 1431655766;
    public static int VX1K = 1261525078;
    public static int VX2K = 1261590614;
    public static int VXSP = 1347639382;
    public static int VYU9 = 961894742;
    public static int VYUY = 1498765654;
    public static int WBVC = 1129726551;
    public static int WHAM = 1296123991;
    public static int WINX = 1481525591;
    public static int WJPG = 1196444247;
    public static int WMV1 = 827739479;
    public static int WMV2 = 844516695;
    public static int WMV3 = 861293911;
    public static int WMVA = 1096174935;
    public static int WNV1 = 827739735;
    public static int WVC1 = 826496599;
    public static int X263 = 859189848;
    public static int X264 = 875967064;
    public static int XLV0 = 810962008;
    public static int XMPG = 1196445016;
    public static int XVID = 1145656920;
    public static int XWV0 = 810964824;
    public static int XWV1 = 827742040;
    public static int XWV2 = 844519256;
    public static int XWV3 = 861296472;
    public static int XWV4 = 878073688;
    public static int XWV5 = 894850904;
    public static int XWV6 = 911628120;
    public static int XWV7 = 928405336;
    public static int XWV8 = 945182552;
    public static int XWV9 = 961959768;
    public static int XXAN = 1312905304;
    public static int Y16 = 909203807;
    public static int Y411 = 825308249;
    public static int Y41P = 1345401945;
    public static int Y444 = 875836505;
    public static int Y8 = 945381215;
    public static int YC12 = 842089305;
    public static int YUV8 = 945182041;
    public static int YUV9 = 961959257;
    public static int YUVP = 1347835225;
    public static int YUY2 = 844715353;
    public static int YUYV = 1448695129;
    public static int YV12 = 842094169;
    public static int YV16 = 909203033;
    public static int YV92 = 842618457;
    public static int ZLIB = 1112099930;
    public static int ZMBV = 1447185754;
    public static int ZPEG = 1195724890;
    public static int ZYGO = 1330075994;
    public static int ZYYY = 1499027802;
}
```

Just call it via:

```
FourCC.IYUV
```

All the best

Chris

Answer (score 1):

I've had great luck using XVID for my FOURCC setting.  It produces the best compression overall for my application.

I noticed that the version of Emgu that I'm using uses a different mechanism for specifying the FOURCC value in the VideoWriter.

The call I used to get the XVID encoder was:

```
    VideoWriter video = new VideoWriter(saveFilename, VideoWriter.Fourcc('X', 'V', 'I', 'D'), fps, videoFrameSize, true);
```

The key was finding that the VideoWriter itself has a way of specifying the Fourcc setting.

```
VideoWriter.Fourcc('X', 'V', 'I', 'D')
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem, for me, was that the `fileName` parameter was expecting backslashes, but I was using forward slashes. For example, `c://work//test1.mp4` throws the exception that the original poster described, but `c:\work\test1.mp4` works.

Answer (score 0):

In my usb webcam i use width = 352 and height = 288 (running well no error), but
if i change width = 460 and height=480 , i get error message "Unable to write video file"

So, the problem is wrong width and height parameters

You can get width using frame.Width and height using frame.Height
you must declare frame variable before like this .

```
Dim frame As Emgu.CV.Image(Of Emgu.CV.Structure.Bgr, Byte) = Capturez.QueryFrame
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and the issue was that frames can only be in Bgr format.
Simply using a format conversion, like:

```
Image<Emgu.CV.Structure.Bgr, byte> frameBgr = frameBgra.Convert<Emgu.CV.Structure.Bgr, byte>();
```

may solve issues with the VideoWriter.